# Parts in TOC with background color

Tags: table-of-contents

How can I modify the part style, so that instead of a rule I get a gray background?
I'm using tocloft package.

\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\mbox{}\protect\hrulefill\par}

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{Part 1}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\mbox{}\protect\hrulefill\par}
\chapter{Lorem ipsum}
\section{Dolor sit amet}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

My solution is to use `tcolorbox` package with redefining a standard class command `\l@part[2]`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@part[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >-2\relax
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \addvspace{2.25em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{3em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=black!10, right=0.5ex, left=0cm, sharpish corners, boxrule=0mm, width=1.01\textwidth]
      {\leavevmode
       \large \bfseries \vbox{\sffamily\bfseries#1}%
      \hb@xt@.5ex{\hss #2}
       }
       \end{tcolorbox}
       \vspace*{1ex}
       \nobreak
         \global\@nobreaktrue
         \everypar{\global\@nobreakfalse\everypar{}}%
    \endgroup
  \fi}
 \makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{Part 1}
\chapter{Lorem ipsum}
\section{Dolor sit amet}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get a white frame around the title? Unfortunately I cannot give an example.

Comment: @Xeo Try to redefine `colback` to `colback=black!30` or something desirable

Comment: Thank you! I solve the issue, it was because of the hyperlinks!!!